# Border-radius not being honored working with bootstrap and angular-material

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material

**Some Context**

I am playing around with Angular-material and trying to see how well it plays with bootstrap. The [Angular-material start project](https://github.com/angular/material-start) shows off some of the cool things it can do, but it seems like it seems like Angular Material still requires a lot of custom CSS for my non-designer skills. Ergo, why I'm trying to see if it's a good idea to try to use bootstrap and angular-material together.

*If this is a terrible idea, please let me know.*

**My Problem**

The icons in the side panel of [this codepen](http://s.codepen.io/troylelandshields/debug/BNYBOa?) should be circles, but they are squares! I can see the border-radius property with Chrome debugger tools but I cannot figure out why it is not being honored.

To add to the mystery, when you click one of the items then all of the icons below that *do in fact become circles for a moment.*

Can someone with more CSS experience than myself tell me what's going on or how I might debug this more completely?

And any feedback about using angular-material + bootstrap together is also much appreciated.

Comment: For some reason, the md-sidenav overflow: auto overrides the elements inside it.

Comment: Hmm ok, thanks for the help. I'll investigate that a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this problem using angular, where the border-radius is not honored, when trying to style an element that is part of a ng-repeat. I found that if you apply the style to the child element of the ng-repeat instead it will honor the border-radius property. This is more of a workaround than a solution, as I also don't understand why this happens.

So in your case you could do:

```
.avatar svg {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```